# Using to letter activation of autohotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have been reading a lot about this on the net, it's not possible as far as I know. In `autohotkeys` you can trigger script with activator keys (<kbd>win</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>) + <kbd>one letter</kbd>(e.g <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> opens notepad etc..). So the question is there any hack or way around or whatever, to be able to activate script with activator key and two or more keys.
Example:  <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (while all keys are pressed down) opens notepad, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> opens chrome, etc. Have someone figure out how to do this. It would be a livesaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"to" = two?

---

> `ctrl+n+o+i` opens chrome

```
#if getKeyState("n") & getKeyState("o")
^i::run chrome.exe
#if
```

Comment: Is that a autohotkey script?

Comment: I don't know how you are but I love you xD. Autohotkeys docs are so bad focused.

Comment: who* , it's the hipe xD